# OCZ RevoDrive X2 runs at half speed

Tags: windows-7, performance, ssd

I have a OCZ RevoDrive X2 128GB in RAID 0 mode (two 55GB partitions) installed on my P55A-UD3 mainobard. I installed a fresh copy of Windows 7 64 bit and provided the OCZ drivers during install. When I run a speed test, I get about half of the performance that tests made me expect to get. Anyone got any ideas ?

My results:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/v4ewbiU.png]

What I expected:

[image: http://archive.benchmarkreviews.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=635&Itemid=99999999&limit=1&limitstart=5]

Comment: The linked benchmarks are not with a RAID.  You can't compare the two benchmarks for that reason.

Comment: So are you saying that OCZ by default ships their drives configured to use a RAID setup specifically aimed at nothing but improving speed, which then lowers speed by half ? I find that extremely hard to believe, and could find no evidence on the net about OCZ basically crippling their drives.

Comment: I assume you have the current firmware and are using a SATA 3 connection?  You linked to benchmarks which has products that don't support dual-partition RAID setup you describe which is the reason I point out the benchmarks are with that feature disabled.

Comment: How I know the benchmark is not in RAID mode is because of the following: `118.6 GB * 2 ~= 223.59 GB`

Comment: That explains it - I was under the impression it was the same device, just with a different size, but apparently, they are quite different, so I was comparing with the wrong device. My bad. Is there a way to delete my question ? It doesn't seem like it would be helpful for anyone to stumble across this.

Comment: It is the same device but the RAID 0 mode is an optional feature is it not?  Your benchmark clearly was in RAID 0 mode because its exactly half of the 223.60GB == 240GB model.

Comment: That's a coincidence - RAID 0 is striping, it doesn't consume extra space.

Comment: Perhaps.  Except there isn't a [128GB](http://ocz.com/consumer/revodrive-3-x2-pcie-ssd/specifications) model

Comment: Riddle solved: despite the serial number of the device ending in -X2, it's not actually a RevoDrive X2 but a regular RevoDrive. My bad, sorry for wasting everyones time.